# Cannot connect to Redis Server via code but can connect via Redis Desktop Manager

Tags: c#, redis

I want to connect to a Redis server and this is the code which I am using:

```
_sentinelHosts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Taurus_Redis_Sentinel_Connection"].Split(',');
        
var masterName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Taurus_Redis_Master_Name"];

        _sentinel = new RedisSentinel(_sentinelHosts, masterName: masterName)
        {
            OnFailover = manager => // Recursive retry on failovers, but give up after max attempts
            {
                Log.Error("Failover detected: " + _sentinel.GetMaster());                                        
                if (_reconnects < MaxReconnects)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Log.Error("Reconnection attempt: " + ++_reconnects);
                    InitializeConnection();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Error("Reconnection exceeded max limit of: " + MaxReconnects);
                    Environment.Exit(1);                        
                }
            },
        };

        _redisManager = _sentinel.Start();
```

On the last line, I get the [errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaZvy.png):

However when I connect the same Redis server via the Redis Desktop Manager, I can connect it successfully.
So what could be the issue with the code? I have double checked and the hosts and the master name is the same in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

please check out the below code sample to setup your Redis connect.

```cs
          ConnectionMultiplexer redis = null;
            string redisConnectionUrl = null;
            {
                var redisSettings = new RedisSettings();
                ConfigurationBinder.Bind(Configuration.GetSection("RedisSettings"), redisSettings);

                if (redisSettings != null)
                {
                    redisConnectionUrl = $"{redisSettings.Url}:{redisSettings.Port},password={redisSettings.Password}";
                }
                else
                {
                    var redisEndpointUrl = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_ENDPOINT_URL") ?? "127.0.0.1:6379").Split(':');
                    var redisHost = redisEndpointUrl[0];
                    var redisPort = redisEndpointUrl[1];

                    var redisPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_PASSWORD");
                    if (redisPassword != null)
                    {
                        redisConnectionUrl = $"{redisHost},password={redisPassword}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        redisConnectionUrl = $"{redisHost}:{redisPort}";
                    }
                }

                redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionUrl);
                services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(redis);
            }
```

```json
//my app.config  

"RedisSettings": {
    "Url": "127.0.0.1",
    "Port": "6379",
    "Password": "123456"
  }
```

Comment: I can connect with this code: ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
            new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                EndPoints = { "server01:6379", "server02:6379" }
            });
            var db = redis.GetDatabase();
            var pong =  db.PingAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(pong);

Comment: So why cant I connect with my original code?

Comment: From your error pic, I clearly see that your Redis Sentinel is not connected. Please check with your config is corretly  aling with  `ConfigurationManager`. And I prefer you to use StackExchange. redis.